# xtable: how to only keep part of the tex output?

Tags: r, latex, xtable

Consider this simple example

```
data <- data.frame(string = c('one','two'))

data
#   string
# 1    one
# 2    two
```

I want to write this `data.frame`  to a `tex` file.

I can use `xtable`

```
xtable(data)
```

with TeX output

```
% latex table generated in R 3.3.1 by xtable 1.8-2 package
% Wed Jan 04 11:39:40 2017
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rl}
  \hline
 & string \\ 
  \hline
1 & one \\ 
  2 & two \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Problem is: I need to get rid of

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rl}
  \hline
```

and

```
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

so that I only have

```
 & string \\ 
  \hline
1 & one \\ 
  2 & two \\ 
   \hline
```

in my `tex` file.

Any ideas how to do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly the point of the `only.contents` argument to `print.xtable`:

```
print(xtable(data), only.contents = TRUE)
```

With TeX output

```
% latex table generated in R 3.3.1 by xtable 1.8-2 package
% Wed Jan  4 11:49:25 2017
 & string \\ 
  \hline
1 & one \\ 
  2 & two \\ 
   \hline
```

(it also has an argument `comment` if you'd like to suppress the TeX comment)